# How to call random picture from MySql database using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql, database

I need to make a call from my webpage to database and select random picture from single table from database. Database is based on server (mysql) and i call it from javascript code. So my question is: Is there a code snippet for that, I am not that good with Javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Javascript can't connect directly to mySQL. What are you using on server side?

Comment: You left out the server-side language you're using.  That's what you need to write an API in.  Also, you might want to show your db schema.

Comment: i am using php as a server side language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in your Server-Side Script. Eg: PHP , ASP.Net

Look this:
[Random images shower](http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/php/show-random-images-050419-1261/)

Maybe it isn't related to question but you should stroe your pics link in database. You should try to store pics in your web-site directory , for example

Comment: Where do i need to put server-side script, in witch directory?

Comment: I think you should use AJAX. Here is a good example:

http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp

Answer (score 1):

You need a server side script that gives you the picture. Then you need some js that loads it.
If you use php, and jQuery on the client-side, your js could look like:

```
$('div#image_container').load('yourscript.php');
```

And then your php would query the database and return something like:

```
<img src="the_random_image_url.jpg" />
```